# Xcode Instruments - How to open the offending file for editing?

Tags: editor, xcode5, instruments, edit-in-place

I'm using a couple of third party libraries that appear to have memory leaks. Instruments highlight the offending lines of code on it's own window, but then I have to look myself in the Xcode editor window for the corresponding file and the particular line of code that is highlighted in Instruments.

**Is there a way to do that directly from Instruments?**

Right clicking the offending lines of code in Instruments brings a sort of generic contextual menu with options like *Look Up "something"* and *Search with Google*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found it, it's the tiny button with the Xcode application icon located at the upper-right corner of the area showing the code, just select the offending code, and then click the icon, it's shown bellow.

[image]